# testing for the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to check if the following series converges. I thought that I have to use comparison test, but it did not lead me anywhere.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{ln^5(2n^7+13)+10sin(n)}{nln^6(n^{7/8}+2n^{1/2}-1)ln(ln(n+(-1)^n))}$$

Comment: For large $n$, the $n$th term is close to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n \ln{n} (\ln{\ln{n}})}$ so the series is divergent.

Comment: I understand your thinking. May I ask you for more formal or more detailed way of writing the solution? I think that this might be the first time I see this kind of checking convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for sufficiently large $n$

$$\frac{\ln^5{(2n^7+13)+10\sin(n)}}{\ln^5{(n^\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1)} > \frac{\ln^5{(2n^7+13)-10}}{\ln^5{(n^\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1)} > 1.$$

Also

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1}{n} = 0,$$

and for sufficiently large $n$ we have

$$ \ln(n^{\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1) < \ln n.$$

Since, $ n+ (-1)^n \leqslant n+1$, we have $\ln \ln (n+ (-1)^n) \leqslant \ln \ln (n+1)$.

Thus, for sufficiently large $n$,

$$\frac{\ln^5{(2n^7+13)+10\sin(n)}}{n\cdot \ln^6{(n^\frac{7}{8}}+2\sqrt{n}-1)\cdot\ln{\ln{(n+(-1)^n}})} > \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln n \cdot \ln \ln (n+1)} \\ > \frac{1}{(n+1) \cdot \ln (n+1) \cdot \ln \ln (n+1)} .$$

The series with terms given by the RHS of the above inequality diverges by the integral test, since

$$\int_2^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1) \cdot \ln (x+1) \cdot \ln \ln (x+1) }= \lim_{x \to \infty}[\ln \ln \ln(x+1)- \ln \ln \ln (3)] = \infty.$$

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using integral?

Comment: The bulk of the work here is to compare with $\frac1{n \ln n \ln \ln (n)}$.  That diverges by the integral test -- which is one of the most elementary tests from calculus. So ask yourself if you can show, for example,  that $\frac1{n \ln n}$ diverges without using the integral test.

Comment: You can use the Cauchy condensation test, but I dont know why that would be preferable to the integral test in this case.

Comment: I think I can, thanks.
We still haven't started doing integrals on university, so there must be some way to do this without using them.

Comment: OK the path is the same -- using the above steps compare with $\frac1{n \ln n \ln \ln n}$, a well-known divergent series, which can be shown to diverge with the Cauchy condenstaion test.

Comment: @miko: You're welcome.  Ratio test, etc. does not work here so I'm pretty sure the point of the exercise is to set up this comparison.